# Get function description in ipython console

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

ipython has a nice feature to tell all the methods that can be called on a object by pressing tab after dot.

Is there a way to get the function description too? This will help one to explore functions in the new libraries easily

Comment: What do you mean by "function description"? You can type `[1] some_function?` (question mark after the function name) to get the help description of the function.

Comment: Yes!...that is what I was looking for. Thank you!